# What happens when you mix antimony pentachloride and hydrochloric acid? Will it form chloroantimonic acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Learning that fluoroantimonic acid, HSbF<sub>6</sub>, is produced by the reaction of antimony pentafluoride and hydrofluoric acid, I wondered if it would do the same for the chlorine. I have seen the other question, but it doesn't describe what would happen if the two compounds were mixed together.

Comment: No, it doesn't describe what would happen if the two compounds were mixed together.

Comment: [Antimony pentachloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimony_pentachloride) reacts with water to form antimony pentoxide and hydrochloric acid, which the linked answer shows further converts to meta-chloroantimonic acid.